# Texture ColorRamp not scaling as expected

Tags: shaders

I'm attempting to create a constant gradient over an array of squares along the X-Axis, but I can't seem to align the ramp correctly.

### -Object Details:

-The Squares are 20m x 20m (I switched to Metric from None in hopes of an easy fix)

-The origin of the square is the origin of the world

-The Array is Constant set to X: +20m, and Y: +1m (To see the Material effect each square)

-The Empty position is -10m on the X-Axis and the scale is 20 on the X-Axis

### -Material Details:

-The Texture Coordinate & ColorRamp are in a group because I have other materials that change the group on other objects (Slight HSV change)

-I've changed the scale of Y-Axis & Z-Axis to 0

### -Question:

I know several workarounds to this issue, but I'd really like to know what's causing this.

### -Pictures:

Ramp 1

[image: Ramp Type 1]

Ramp 2

[image: Ramp Type 1]

Node Group Setup

[image: Node Group Setup]

Overview using Ramp 1

[image: Overview 1]

Overview 1 Close-up using Ramp 1 (Left Side)

[image: Overview 1 Close-up 1]

Overview 1 Close-up using Ramp 1 (Middle)

[image: Overview 1 Close-up 2]

Comment: Try adding "separate XYZ" node before "Mapping…"